# Silverlight: Set one image source equal to another

Tags: image, silverlight, expression-blend

I'm building a very simple video player in Silverlight (using Expression Blend 4), and I want to have an Image that comes from the same image file as another Image. (The image files are just in the root of my project.) If someone selects my first video thumbnail in one area, the detail view for the selected video also includes this thumbnail.

I'd love to just do this (in the C# code-behind):

```
videoDetailImage.Source = _currentThumb.Source;
```

But it seems to have no effect. I've played around with:

```
videoDetailImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("t01-artifact.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```

And that doesn't work either. I've even tried grabbing images from the web and going UriKind.Absolute - still nothing shows up.

Update: I actually gave up on this and did a very lazy thing of just putting all the images I needed into the app and toggling their Visible / Collapsed states. It's a piece of junk, but all that mattered was that it work.

Comment: videoDetailImage and currentThumb are both BitmapImage? If so I would assume your videoDetailImage is maybe not rendered in a correct way (bad binding or size error?) Because videoDetailImage.Source = _currentThumb.Source; looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have kind of given up on this - I ended up just putting all the images I needed in and toggling their Visible / Collapsed state. You can tell what my interest level in proceeding with Silverlight is. :-)